# Assignin in second level struct

Tags: matlab, dynamic-variables

I am dealing with a small tricky issue in matlab:

I want to assign values to a dynamically created struct (2. level):

my struct looks like this:

```
a.b.c = 1    %Creates a struct with two levels
```

now I want to autofill `a.b` with `c1, c2, c3,...cn` as neighbor-elements to `c`. Also the firste leven `b` must be changed dynamically, so I can not hardcode any 'path'...All values consist of a prefix (e.g. b or c) and a postfix (just a number increased by a loop)

My main concern is, that this process MUST be done by a loop and not by hand (otherwise I would do many copy/paste lines with manual edits).

It would be great if someone could give me a hint.

greets, poeschlorn

Comment: Could you give more detail as to *why* you have to do things this way and what specific processing steps you are performing (a general outline of your loops would suffice)? As Edric mentions below, there may be a much better way to organize your data than having to create structure fields in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for. It uses dynamic field names to create eleven b entries and *n* c entries:

```
>> n = 5;
>> for ii = 1:11
for jj = 1:n
a.b(ii).(sprintf('c%u', jj)) = 1;
end
end
>> a

a = 

    b: [1x11 struct]

>> a.b(1)

ans = 

    c1: 1
    c2: 1
    c3: 1
    c4: 1
    c5: 1

>> a.b(3)

ans = 

    c1: 1
    c2: 1
    c3: 1
    c4: 1
    c5: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

b3's solution shows you how to create the fields with a loop, but please "don't do that". Can't you use a cell array? E.g.

```
a.b.c = cell( 1, n );
for ii=1:n
  a.b.c{ii} = rand(ii);
end
```